# Transition for max-height is super laggy

Tags: reactjs, css-transitions

I am trying to create an accordion of some sort. The idea is that I get the height of the element through `useEffect` and `useRef` from React, and then apply it when a button is clicked, and after that transition the height/max-height, e.g.

```
const Accordion = props => {
  const [isOpen, toggleOpen] = useCycle(false, true)
  const contentRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    contentRef.current.style.maxHeight = isOpen
      ? `${contentRef.current.scrollHeight}px`
      : `0px`
  }, [contentRef, isOpen])

return (

<div
      ref={contentRef}
      className={cx(styles['accordion-content'], {
        [styles['is-active']]: isOpen,
      })}
    >
      {props.children}
    </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

However, this transition is super laggy, and I am not sure how to accomplish this in any other way ? I don't feel like there are transforms that can do what height/max-height is doing. So what is the way to go in order to create smooth expansion effects ?

Comment: Here is a minimal example and it's smooth: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-wildflower-lzc70?file=/src/App.js
-
I don't see how you do the animated transition in your code.

Comment: Hmmm, I'm sorry about that. Well, I actually use CSS to transition, while you use it directly through React. I have no idea if it is that that makes the difference ? I just have a class added when clicking, which then has a transition for `max-height` which is set by the `contentRef`.